# Is SQL Server capable of sending certificate chain to the client?

Tags: certificate, sql-server

I wonder if SQL Server is capable of sending certificate chain to the client, I tried every option while creating certificates and I am aware of what restrictions SQL Server puts on a certificate to be eligible to be applied on the server.

To be more specific I have a 'root' certificate in the client truststore and there is an intermediate CA and also a server certificate on the server but Sql Server sends the server certificate only to the client(Java App). I use Windows 10, Sql Server 2016, Java 1.8 as client.

Comment: See also [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/128148) on dba.stackexchange; it fails to provide a solution however.

Comment: Thanks, but I already saw the post, and I suspected that Sql Server could not send the chain but I am not sure.

Comment: This really would not provide much value because it would be up to the client to trust them, which would not be conducive to security to do. It also would not be useful for convenience for making the root/intermediate certificates available because SQL Server does not present certificates in a convenient way to the consumer as with a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it does not, and that common practice is to require the intermediate certs to be installed on the Client.

[This AWS page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Concepts.General.SSL.Using.html), for example, discusses installing the necessary CA and intermediate certs on the client to connect to their hosted MS-SQL instances.

The same question was [asked on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/128148) a couple years ago, and mostly through the comment thread, seems to have concluded the same thing.

While the same setup would be unpalatable with web browsers, which are many-to-many, it is more manageable (but still ugly) with SQL clients, which are few-to-fewer.